# Change the number in a <strong> element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have list elements like so:

```
<li>
<strong style="color: #BBB;">1</strong>
<a href="">Matt</a>
<b>4 days ago</b>
<img id="911" class="commentlike" src="../Images/likesred.png">
<p>20ptanswerlol</p>
</li>
```

I currently have an onclick event for the img, and it works perfectly. What i am trying to do is make the onclick event in jquery change the number "1" in the  to a 0 or 2. Basically i want the text inside to add one or subtract one.

first i have to find the  element, but i can't seem to do so... Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the `<strong>` tag from the `<img>`:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    var strongTag = $(this).prevAll('strong');
});
```

And to retrieve, increment and update it's value:

```
var number = parseInt(strongTag.text(), 10);
number++;
strongTag.text(number);
```

So now we have:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    var strongTag = $(this).prevAll('strong');

    var number = parseInt(strongTag.text(), 10);    // Parse integer
    number++;    // Increment number by 1
    strongTag.text(number);    // Set the <strong>'s text to new number
});
```

To subtract 1, just do `number--` or whatever other logic you need to.

Comment: Use `parseInt(strongTag.text(), 10);`. Specifying the radix is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<strong style="color: #BBB;" id="field_name">1</strong>    

$('img').click(function() {
    $("#field_name").update("New text");
});
```